# How to start Flask and Flask-SocketIO via the command line flask run

Tags: flask

I started with an application that has several webservices defined. I was able to start the application via `flask run` on the command line. Afterwards, I integrated flask-sckoetio (i.e. I added the lines `from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit` and `socketio = SocketIO(app)`) and now I'm not able anymore to start the server via `flask run`.

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/do_sth', methods=['POST'])
def do_sth():
    return ""
```

I get the following message on the console:

```
 * Serving Flask-SocketIO app "webservices.py"
 * Forcing debug mode off
WebSocket transport not available. Install eventlet or gevent and gevent-websocket for improved perform
ance.
c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py:496: Warning: Silently ignoring
app.run() because the application is run from the flask command line executable.  Consider putting app.
run() behind an if __name__ == "__main__" guard to silence this warning.
  use_reloader=use_reloader, **kwargs)
```

So I updated my code to this:

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/do_sth', methods=['POST'])
def do_sth():
    return ""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

But I still get the same error message and the server doesn't start. However, if I just execute the script everything works. But why is `flask run` not possible anymore?

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of variable `__name__` is equal to `"__main__"` only when the file called directly with a command like `python file.py`. But your file was *imported* and his `__name__` variable is setted to name of a module which import them.

Solution:

Just delete string `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install [eventlet](http://eventlet.net/) or [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/), which are mentioned in the error message?

They are also listed under requirements in [flask-socketIO documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
Try installing them first.

After installing one of them, you can just use `flask run` to start your application.